# Stop entering values into array when enter is pressed

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello guys I'm having trouble trying to implement the enter key part of my program

```
int list[50];
int i = 0;
while (/*enter key has not been pressed*/&& i < 50){
  cin>>list[i];
  i++;
  }
```

How its supposed to work is, it will take in integers separated by spaces and store them into the array. It should stop accepting input when the enter key has been pressed.

PS I'm posting this from my phone that's why I can't format the text properly. If there's any problem with syntax, it could probably just be ignored setting as I'm only concerned with the"enter key" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a string stream, basically you read the whole line into a string and then you start reading integers from that string into your array.
reading a string will terminate when you hit enter, so I think that would work out for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace :: std; // bad idea, I am just lazy to type "std" so much
int main (){


    const int arrSize = 5;

    int arr [arrSize] = {0}; //initialize arr zeros
    string line;
    getline(cin,line);


    cout <<"you entered " << line<<endl; // just to check the string you entered
    stringstream ss (line);

    int i = 0;
    while ( ss>>arr[i++] && i < arrSize); // this might look a bit ugly


    for (int i =0; i < arrSize; i++) // checking the content of the list
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";

    getchar();


    return 0;



}
```

note that doesn't test for false input from the user ( like a letter instead of a number).

Comment: I believe you need to `#include <cstdio>` for that code to compile, due to the call to `getchar()`

Comment: I tried the code on VS 2012 and it worked, I guess `cstdio` is included indirectly somehow through `<iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

They key here is to use the `break` keyword.

```
int list[50];
int i = 0;
int input;
while (i < 50){
  cin >> input;
  if(input == '\n') break;
  list[i] = input;
  i++;
}
```

Im guessing you are new to proramming, so comparing an `int` to a `char` might seem a little strange to you. Basically, all `chars` are also `int`s in ASCII form.

Comment: what if wanted to insert `10` which is the ascii value of new line

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Then you are boned :P 10 is such a boring number anyways, why would you want that? In all seriousness tough, that is a good point and im not sure. You would probably have to rearchitechture this to accept strings and then check for 10 or newline in string format